# sql server 2000: Short cut for getting stored proc text

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, query-analyzer

what is the short cut to get entire text of the stored proc in query analyzer. I know that I could highlight table name and hit <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> and get the entire table structure.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to not exist a shorcut with your exact request. If you want to see the complete list of query analyzer shorcuts visit the folowing link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa216992(SQL.80).aspx

Anyway you can modify, customize or create your own shorcuts. 
For examle ALT+F1 just executes the "sp_help" stored procedure. 
Check the documentation at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa216956(SQL.80).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to add a [shortcut](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa216956(SQL.80).aspx) that uses [`sp_helptext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933450(SQL.80).aspx), rather then `sp_help`